Entering the US with a hotel reservation booked under my brother's name
I will be traveling to Miami with my brother for one week. We booked a hotel on booking.com for 2 adults, but the hotel is booked under my brother's name. If immigration asks where I'm staying, will this be accepted?

Are you travelling with your brother? I.e. are you entering immigration at same time? In such case you can (and should) both be screened together. Else better that brother is reachable with mobile phone when you are doing immigration in case of questions. I travelled a lot with my parents and related people, and I do not remember to give details to each person to hotel (contrary on UK where they may ask such info).

Almost certainly yes. Especially if you can show a copy of the booking. Certainly yes if you are travelling with your brother, who can be there to tell them that he booked the room.
If you are in doubt, call the hotel and have your name added to the booking.
